# TLS extension Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation in SunJSSE

Tags: java, tls1.2, jsse

I am currently implementing a TLSv1.2 server simulator by using **SunJSSE of JDK10** for testing a resources-limited client. The client sends Client Hello with Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation extension to ask for 512 bytes of TLSPlaintext.fragment as per defined in
[RFC 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066).

Refer to this [CR of OpenJDK](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~xuelei/8043758.spec/spec.txt) item 11, I call `setMaximumPacketSize(517)` for maximum fragment length **512** bytes that required by the client + **5** bytes of TLS record header in the server simulator, but the result of fragmentation seems was done on the Handshake messages instead of the TLS record.

Here is the Wireshark captured log of first TLS record sent by my server simulator:

[TLS fragmented record by setting jsse.enableMFLNExtension = true and maximum packet size = 517](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt5Wi.png)

I can see the Server Hello consumed 74 bytes while the Server Certificate consumed 512 bytes, that is why the length is 586. The client under test aborted the handshake with Alert(record_overflow) because it found the  `length` > negotiated length i.e. 512 bytes.

My questions are:

1. Is my configuration correct for the MFLN? My code as below:

   ```
   // enable Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation
   System.setProperty("jsse.enableMFLNExtension", "true");

   Socket serverSocket = srvSock.accept();
   SSLParameters sslParams = ((SSLSocket) serverSocket).getSSLParameters();
   int maxPacketSize = (int) 517;

   sslParams.setMaximumPacketSize(maxPacketSize);
   ((SSLSocket) serverSocket).setSSLParameters(sslParams);
   ```
2. The Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation extension is not included in Server Hello (please check the image above), but the TLS record is fragmented, is this behavior accepted?
3. Is current implementation (JDK v10.0.1) of SunJSSE on fragmentation wrong? I checked the [OpenJDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk9u/jdk/rev/3abd28d7136d), it has a System property of **jsse.enableMFLExtension** instead of **jsse.enableMFL*N*Extension** that defined in [JSSE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-41D5F11E-81BD-4C03-A315-48016D9B9B36).

Thanks in advance for any guidance and opinion.